# unable to handle validation property in x-editable popup field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I was able to handle the submit event but unable to handle the validation property in editable.

Below is my code :

HTML Code

```
<a id="aspPhoneNumber" class="edit labelProps editable editable-click editable-empty" style="word-wrap:break-word;" data-original-title="" title="">Empty</a>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#aspPhoneNumber').editable({
            type: 'text',
            placement: 'right',
            success: function (response, newValue) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
     $('#aspPhoneNumber').editable('option','validate', function (v) {
            alert("this"+v);
            if ($.trim(v) == '') { return 'Required field!'; }
        });
    $('.editable-submit').on('click', function () {
            alert("submited");
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word "Empty" from your editable HTML to make it a truly empty/null value.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZSX2/

```
<a id="aspPhoneNumber" class="edit labelProps editable editable-click editable-empty" style="word-wrap:break-word;" data-original-title="" title=""></a>
```